# Erro ao pegar ID ou Position dentro de um Spinner

Tags: android

Fala pessoal, estou tentando pegar o id ou o position dentro de um ArrayView do componente Spinner porem ele não esta ficando dentro da variável. Se eu colocar um Toast para exibir o id ou a posição, o Toast exibe normalmente. Estou querendo guardar dentro dessa variavel para poder testar o valor em um (if e else) e mostrar o conteudo de acordo com o que o usuário escolher no spinner.

```
private Spinner spinnerIdade; 
private int posicao;    
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

spinnerIdade = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_Idade);
     ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,
            R.array.spinner_idade, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1);

    spinnerIdade.setAdapter(adapter);
 AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener escolha = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        posicao = spinnerIdade.getSelectedItemPosition();
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ID: " + posicao, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
};
    spinnerIdade.setOnItemSelectedListener(escolha);
```

E o IF Else para fazer o teste

```
        if(posicao == 0) {
            int x = Integer.parseInt(idade.getText().toString()) - 15;
            int y = (Integer.parseInt(salario.getText().toString()) * x) / 100;
        } else if (posicao == 1) {
            int x = Integer.parseInt(idade.getText().toString()) - 10;
            int y = (Integer.parseInt(salario.getText().toString()) * x) / 100;
        } else if (posicao == 2) {
             int x = Integer.parseInt(idade.getText().toString()) - 15;
            int y = (Integer.parseInt(salario.getText().toString()) * 50) / 100;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Verifique as opções e tente novamente",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Esse `if/else` está onde?

Comment: Criei um um método "calcula" e coloquei ele dentro, fora do onCreate. Quando clico no botão Resultado, ele chama o método "calcula".

Comment: posicao = position

Comment: @Luc Ele diz que o Toast exibe o valor correctamente.

Comment: @ramaral, digo, ele chama o onItemSelected que dá a ele a posição do item, então, no mesmo método, ele faz uma busca no spinner pra saber a posição do item selecionado. É meio redundante, não? Ou a posição do método é diferente da do spinner?

Comment: @Luc Sim isso é verdade, é redundante. No entanto fazer `posição = position` não resolverá o problema já que `position` é igual a `getSelectedItemPosition()`. Note que ele usa `posicao` no Toast e ele diz que exibe o valor correcto.

Comment: Sim... é estranho. :o

Comment: Fiz a seguinte alteração pessoal: Na MainActivity coloquei implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, criando dois metódos publicos.(onItemSelected e onNothingSelected).
Dentro do método onItemSelected coloquei a variável posição recebendo o parâmetro ID do método. Ai sim, consegui pegar a seleção dentro do spinner e fazendo o if/else de acordo com o resultado da posição.

Adicionei também no onCreate ,
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerIdade.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

Removi o AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não vejo razão para isso acontecer.
No entanto, se a razão do `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` é apenas para "setar" o atributo `posicao`, para depois saber qual é o item seleccionado no Spinner em outro local, não necessita de o fazer.
O método `getSelectedItemPosition()` pode ser usado para esse efeito.

Assim, em vez de um atributo, declare no método `calcula` uma variável e use-a nos *if's*

```
    ...
    int posicao = spinnerIdade.getSelectedItemPosition();
    if(posicao == 0) {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(idade.getText().toString()) - 15;
        int y = (Integer.parseInt(salario.getText().toString()) * x) / 100;
    } else if (posicao == 1) {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(idade.getText().toString()) - 10;
        int y = (Integer.parseInt(salario.getText().toString()) * x) / 100;
    } else if (posicao == 2) {
         int x = Integer.parseInt(idade.getText().toString()) - 15;
        int y = (Integer.parseInt(salario.getText().toString()) * 50) / 100;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Verifique as opções e tente novamente",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```